# How to use two types of editing like popup and Inline in a single kendo Grid in asp?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

**I want to use two types of editing like inline editing and popup editing for a single kendo grid
inline editing for Commands
popup editing for Toolbar,,
alredy i searched google but i didnt get related pages
in popup editing i want to use template**

`<script id="customPopUpTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">`
`<form id="myForm" action="" method="post">`
`<div align="right">`
`<span id="Spn2" class ="span">* Mandatory Fields</span>`
`</div>`

`<div align="center">`
`<span id="Spn1" class ="span1" ></span>`
`</div>`

`<div class="heig"> </div>`

`<div class="k-edit-field">`
`<input name="FirstName" class="k-textbox"/>`
`<span id="sta1" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;">`
 `</span>`
`</div>`
`<div class="div">First Name: </div>`

`<div class="k-edit-field">`
`<input name="LastName" class="k-textbox"/>`
`<span id="sta2" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;">`
 `</span>`
`</div>`

`<div class="div">Last Name: </div>`

`<div class="k-edit-field">`
`<input name="LoginName" class="k-textbox"/>`<
`<span id="sta3" style="color: Red; font-size:medium;">`
`</span>`
`</div><div class="div">Login Name: </div>`

`<div class="k-edit-field">`
`<input name="Password" type="Password" class="k-textbox"/>`
`<span id="sta4" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;">`
`</span>`
`</div>`
`<div class="div">Password: </div>`

`<div class="k-edit-field">`
`<input name="ReTypePassword" type="Password" class="k-textbox"/>`
`<span id="sta5" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;"> * </span>`
`</div> <div class="div">ReTypePassword: </div>`

`<div class="k-edit-field">
 <input name="ScopeId"`
`data-bind="value:ScopeId"`
`data-value-field="ScopeId"`
`data-text-field="ScopeName"`
`data-source="dropDownDataSource"`
`data-role="dropdownlist" />`
`<span id="sta6" style="color: Red; font-size:medium ;"> * </span>`

`</div>`
`<div class="div">Scope: </div>`

`</form>`
`</script>`

my  template id is customPopUpTemplate

My toolbar  code is

`toolbar: [ { text : "Add new record", name: "popup", iconClass: "k-icon k-add"} ],`
**`editable: "inline",`**

`columns:`
`[`

`{`
`field: "LoginName",`
`title: "Login Name",`
`width:"175px"`
`},`
`{`
`field: "FirstName",`
`title: "First Name",`
`width:"115px"`
`},`
`{`
`field: "LastName",`
`title: "Last Name",`
`width:"100px"`
`}`

`$(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {` 
`grid.options.editable = "popup";`
`grid.addRow();`
`grid.options.editable = "inline";`
`});`

its working fine but it will display normal columns,,

in my template i add extra columns ,,

how to i use my template for popup editing...

thanks in advance.!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a json values having options templates ,mode.. to grid.options.editable

```
$(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () { 

var popupWithOption = {
                     mode: "popup",
                     template: kendo.template($("#customPopUpTemplate").html()),
                     window: {
                         title: "Your Title"
                     }
                 };
grid.options.editable = popupWithOption ;
grid.addRow();
grid.options.editable = "inline";
});
```

i hope this will help you